# Lucene search for a filename, using WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Tags: solr, lucene

If I search for toto.pdf, a token "pdf" is created for the search tI'm indexing some data, including filenames.

What I want is, according to indexed filename:

```
MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg
```

And to be able tosearch it with:

```
supercool
supercool123
123
girlfriend
jpg
```

So at index it pretty easy to be able to use WordDelimiterFilterFactory so that some tokens are created, like:

```
my
supercool
mysupercool
mysupercool123
supercool123
123
girlfriend
jpg
girlfriend.jgp
etc...
```

The matter is that at search time, I don't really know what I should do.

If I use WordDelimiterFilterFactory at search time, `MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg` would match even with `toto.jpg` because in both cases a token `jpg` is created.
`toto.jpg` should not be in the result list at all, so it's not a solution for me to have both results with the appropriate one having a better scoring

---

Have you any recommendation to index and search for filenames?

Comment: Are you sure that `toto.pdf` would match `MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg`? Cause I sure don't see either `toto` or `pdf` in `MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg`.

Comment: that's right, I meant toto.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific example of yours i.e. if the search is for `MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg` and you want this to only return documents that have the entire string in it, you can keep a [copyField](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields), say named `filename_str`, whose fieldType is `string`. String matches will ensure you that you get an exact match. This could be a first-level "exact match" search you do.

However, I am guessing that you would want a search for `123girlfriend.jpg` to return the document containing `MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg`. You can do a 2nd level search for this. Beginning Solr 4.0 you can do a regex search like

```
q=filename_str:/.*123girlfriend.jpg/
```

(This regex query should also work for `filename` field itself, if you are using `preserveOriginal=1` in WordDelimiterFilterFactory at index time.)
Else you can do a [leading wild-card search](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Wildcard+Queries), which works in earlier Solr versions too.

If you also want `MySupercool.jpg` to match `MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg`, then I guess you would have to manually do the work of DelimiterFilterFactory and construct a regex query like

```
q=filename_str:/.*My.*Supercool.*.jpg/
```

Another issue is that `jpg` is going to match lot of documents, so you may want to split the filename and the extension and keep them as separate fields.

Comment: Doing wildcard/regex query is pretty slow no? Ok so in the end there is no simple solution for that I guess.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about your problem, I guess the last comment I made about splitting the filename and the extension and keeping them in separate fields should help you eliminate a lot of false matches, even without making any other changes.

Comment: We may do that, was just looking for an easier solution without having to split the data before insert, or creating a custom analyzer/filter

Answer (score 1):

Can you come up with some meaningful for your use case DisMax mm parameter?

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29

E.g.
mm=100% and "MySupercool123girlfriend.jpg" would match only filenames that have all ["my", "supercool", "123", "girlfriend", "jpg"] terms in them

You can find some less strict but still giving relevant results expression. See http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/doc-files/min-should-match.html

Comment: I saw this feature but can't really use it because I need a strict result, because we have to sort the result by creation date and not by scoring. Thus having something like 20% may not be appropriate for our usecase and would feel more like a hacky solution that may or not give good results

Comment: Maybe you can a) disable tf and idf in score calculation by implementing custom Similarity (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825170/ignore-tf-idf-at-query-time-in-solr) and b) sorting by score desc, timestamp desc. Thus you would have strict matches first sorted by timestamp, then matches without 1 term, etc. Or you can just sort by score but boost recent results (see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents)

Comment: The point is actually to keep the timestamp ordering first, and to not use a custom component. We may use a custom component in the future, but for now I just want a prebuilt solution. Thanks anyway