# How do I override Solr's relevancy in a query

Tags: solr, lucene

I am integrating a chemical structure search with Solr. To that end I am creating a Solr plugin.
The structure search returns the structure_id and it's score. Scores are values between 100 and 0 (probably would never see a 0)
I use this to create a Solr query to pull all documents that have the structure_ids. I want the results of the search to be ordered by the structure search score, not the Solr relevancy.

I generate a query that looks like this:
+structure_id:(28760263^95 OR 30392284^82 OR 47390042^70)

The problem is that in my trivial test case Solr is returning the records matching the structure_id 28760263 last. It has assigned it the lowest relevancy (4.6609402E-6)!
I wrote a function to basically amplify the score by a lot and that apparently does fix the problem however I don't think that the amplification should be necessary.
I am using Solr 3.5. 
Is there some configuration that I am missing? Currently I am using Solr pretty much out of the box. The only things I've changed is to add my plugin and I edited the example docs to add structure_ids for my test case.

Is there a way to completely override the lucene scoring with the score from the structure search? We have other reasons why we would like to take control of Solr's scoring and knowing how to do that would be useful

Comment: I think I know why this behaves as it does. This is an extremely small data set of 5 documents. The structure search in question returns ~6000 hits of which 4 documents match. 2 of the 4 are the same structure_id. It is these 2 that appear to be out of order. I think that given 2/5 are duplicates in the search, Solr is giving them a lower relevancy than the others. This seems clear when I enter a normal query into solr with debug set. Is that the case?

Comment: You can use the score "explain" option in Solr interface to see which components in the query are getting scored in unwanted way. BTW, what do you want to change in the Lucene scoring formula? Add additional factors? Come up with a new formula? What's your plan exactly?

Comment: The problem turns out to be Solr/lucene IDF.
Overriding it as described here fixes the problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825170/ignore-tf-idf-at-query-time-in-solr

Comment: @phani My application chemical structure search has it's own concept of relevancy, which is returned by the structure search. This relevancy is much more relevant to the end users than the similarity calculated by Lucene.
In order to get the results ordered as I need I am boosting the structure_ids that I am passing to Solr by the score returned by the structure search. Now that I have Lucene's IDF turned off it seems to be working

Comment: if you've already found the solution, carry on :)

Comment: Out of interest: Do you plan on making this plugin publicly available like on github or such?