# Searching related stories based on tag on priority basis

Tags: java, solr, lucene, related-content

I need to search related stories based on the tags of a story..

Say I have a story with 4 tags so my related story logic will be

- **Step 1**: Search all 4 Tags under a story >> Display story
- **Step 2**: Search for 3 Tags creating different permutation &    combination related to Tags >> Display story
- **Step 3**: Search for 2 Tags creating different permutation &    combination related to Tags >> Display story
- **Step 4**: Search for a Tag one after the other, if found display the    same in “More Like This” field.

How can I achieve this. I am a newbee in Solr Please guide me...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Thomas What I actually want to do is, if a story has all 4 of the tags mentioned in my parent story, it will come in number 1 in result, then stories with at least 3 tags in them if avail able and then with 2 tags and so on...

Comment: Hmm, in that case you might want to look into how lucene/solr does its scoring but afaik if you search for 4 (optional) tags the score should be the higher the more matches you get. So you might be able to just issue a corresponding query and be done (something like `tags:tag1 OR tags:tag2 etc.` - not entirely sure on the exact syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' suggestion in the comments is a good idea, but can give you the wrong result - for example if you have two very common tags and two that's unique to the two stories in question. I.e.:

- Story 1 (foo, bar, the, is)
- Story 2 (foo, bar, ask, barf)
- Story 3 (baz, bar, the, is)
- .. repeat thousands of other stories with "the" and "is" as tags

If you search for `tag:(foo OR bar OR the OR is)` when displaying the first entry, you *might* get Story 2 instead - as it has the most "valuable" tags (and the default calculation for Solr uses the number of times the term appear in the document divided by the total number of documents it appears in).

The *best* result is probably (this will depend on your use case) still Story 2, but if you *really* want to get the document which matches three of the tags, you'll have to do it a different way.

If you need the second option, you can solve this by using a function query: `termfreq` returns the number of times a term is in the document (and if your tags are distinct in the document, this will be `1`). `sum` allows you to sum the values from each function, so something like:

```
sum(termfreq(tag, 'foo'), termfreq(tag, 'bar'), termfreq(tag, 'the'), termfreq('is'))
```

.. would give you a distinct tag count for each document that you use for sorting.

You also have the option of using a custom Similarity class, which would return the same similarity score for each term (and depending on the Solr version you're using, similarity may be set for each field (and not for just the core)). I don't think there's one included, [but there's plenty of examples available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825170/ignore-tf-idf-at-query-time-in-solr).